# Passar o valor da chave primária de uma tabela para a estrangeira de outra tabela PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu já usei MAX(nome_da_coluna), last_insertid, e nada funciona, a chave estrangeira da segunda tabela continua recebendo valor 0.

```
public function cadastrar_teste($nr_ficha_teste, $cod_refugo_teste, 
   $qtd_refugo, $codigo_profissional){

    $conexao = Database::getConnection();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO teste (nr_ficha_teste, cod_refugo_teste, qtd_refugo, cod_usuario_profissional)
            VALUES ('$nr_ficha_teste', '$cod_refugo_teste', '$qtd_refugo', '$codigo_profissional');";

    $conexao->exec($sql);
}
```

```
 require "../Models/Teste.php";
 require "../Models/Profissional.php";
 require_once "../Models/Cabecalho.php";

 $ficha = new Cabecalho();
 $nr_ficha = $ficha->busca_ficha();
 $cod_refugo_teste = $_POST['cod_refugo_teste'];
 $qtd_refugo = $_POST['qtd_refugo'];
 $codigo = $_POST['cod_usuario_profissional'];
 $valoresrefugos = explode(",",$cod_refugo_teste);
 $valoresqtds = explode(",",$qtd_refugo);

 $unir = 'INSERT INTO teste (cod_refugo_teste, qtd_refugo) VALUES (';
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($valoresrefugos); $i++) {
     if ($i == count($valoresrefugos) - 1) {
    $unir .= "'" . $valoresrefugos[$i] . "','" . $valoresqtds[$i] . "')";
}
else {
    $unir .= "'" . $valoresrefugos[$i] . "','" . $valoresqtds[$i] . "'), (";
  }
 }



 if (is_numeric($codigo)){          
$teste = new Teste();
$teste->cadastrar_teste($nr_ficha, $cod_refugo_teste, $qtd_refugo, $codigo);
header("location:../?pgs=modal_cadastro_teste");
    }else{
        echo "Erro!";
    }
```

.

```
public function busca_ficha(){
$conexao = Database::getConnection();

$select="SELECT MAX(nr_ficha) FROM cab_teste";

  $busca = $conexao->query($select);
  $nr_ficha = $busca->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $nr_ficha;
 }
```

nr_ficha é a chave primária da tabela 1.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nr_ficha_teste é a chave estrangeira da tabela 2.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UM ADENDO:** o valor estava recebendo valor zero porque não estava realmente como chave estrangeira, MAS eu ainda não consigo passar valor algum pra nr_ficha_teste. Agora que eu conectei as duas tabelas, a FK da tabela 2 recebe valor NULL.

Comment: Coloque a função `busca_ficha()` na pergunta. Provavelmente o valor que vem de lá é 0

Comment: Pronto, coloquei.

Comment: Silvia, realmente precisa ser via PHP? É muito mais simples e rápido direto no SQL.

Comment: Você diz fazer apenas uma consulta? Bom, eu precisaria do PHP porque esse é um projeto web.

Comment: O que você quer fazer é alteração de 2 tabelas. Não poderia ser direto no banco, com `update`? Por que criar tudo em PHP para fazer isso? Será uma rotina ou é uma "correção"?

Comment: Não quero fazer um update, quero passar o valor de uma chave pra outra. A chave estrangeira da tabela 2 não tem valor nenhum.

Comment: ainda precisa de ajuda?

Comment: Sim, não consegui resolver o problema. Me aparece um erro assim:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 0):

Galera, consegui resolver. O problema não estava no banco e sim, no php. Na hora de passar o valor, eu transformei a variável em um array. Para fazer com que o array funcione, basta, NO MEU CASO, dar um apelido à coluna e passar esse apelido como parâmetro. Ficou assim:

```
public function busca_ficha(){
 $conexao = Database::getConnection();

 $select="SELECT MAX(nr_ficha) AS ULTIMO FROM cab_teste";

 $busca = $conexao->query($select);
 $nr_ficha = $busca->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 return $nr_ficha[0]['ULTIMO'];
}
```